# Mostrar parte de un archivo en c++

Tags: c++

¿Es posible mostrar un numero determinado de conjunto de líneas de un archivo? Por ejemplo tengo esta parte de un código que muestra todas las ordenes hechas de un menú en restaurante, si quisiera mostrar solo las ultimas 10 o 15 ordenes hechas ¿Qué comandos puedo utilizar?

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Spanish");
int Dia, Mes, opc_menu;
double Monto;

Lec.open("Ordenes.txt", ios::in);
if(Lec.is_open()){

    cout << "Ultimas ordenes" << endl << endl;

    Lec>>Dia;

    while(!Lec.eof()){
        Lec>>Mes;
        Lec>>opc_menu;
        Lec>>Monto;
        cout << "Dia------------------:" << Dia << endl;
        cout << "Mes------------------:" << Mes << endl;
        cout << "Numero de menu-------:" << opc_menu << endl;
        cout << "Monto a pagar--------:" << Monto << endl;
        cout << "----------------------" << endl;
        Lec>>Dia;
    }
    Lec.close();
}else
cout << "Error al abrir el archivo" << endl;
system ("pause");
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que investigues sobre la funcion `getline`

Comment: quieres ver esto [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Es posible mostrar un numero determinado de conjunto de líneas de un archivo?

Si, no, puede, depende.

---

Es posible mostrar partes de un archivo, el cómo separes esas partes es arbitrario, ya sea por espacios o por saltos de línea. Pero separes como separes las líneas tendrás que leer el archivo completo para obtener una parte del mismo. Una posible opción sería esta:

```
std::list<std::string> leer_ultimas_lineas(unsigned lineas, const std::string &archivo)
{
    std::list<std::string> resultado;

    if (std::ifstream i{archivo})
    {
        std::string linea;
        while (std::getline(i, linea))
        {
            resultado.push_back(linea);
            if (resultado.size() > lineas)
            {
                resultado.pop_front();
            }
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}

int main()
{
    for (const auto &linea : leer_ultimas_lineas(10, "Ordenes.txt"))
    {
        std::cout << linea << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZRbb4IwFMef6ac4cYlCosYLT2p82uu2L2BCOqh4MmhJL26Z8bO7UnBidN2DTQjlXP799XDatKpGaUF5fjo9IU8LkzFYoVBaMlquycW2vTVZC/K8aylQ6TUhe4EZZFQLlWimdBiRAwlwC6HS2WIhWikQh96bzBhnaqy/dO8YkcDGBQJWK/sKes9IRzdjMd3wnnO/MOVzv5qSSQEWq2Tc3GYLrgVQqGhO5W326O44e@@TzfxkMz/ZzE82e4Rs7ieb@8nmfrL5I2Sxnyz2k8V@svhfsiUJjuRIiGvMuntXbtZ2NhSMycQUGkuqkgI5oyo0XGHOWQbN9xBSwZWGTh70qUx3uBeu7/@QlkxZYZqJJemcDTyfDTy0GudT0dV3K1v04HOHBWtTc6Zre4jDxh/ZRJcZ/C41rozaJe80/QibkFrDLX4JUfjNwgjW7fZqkUalKyOqZCttycNG4UjcY@tog7SRvLs7a0WuoaTIm4ugezHY9K2QEDY1pMb@xL5bGBZ3iz@dDOHq0oi65UmF0fbyaNDryWDDB8srsIkFOp1@AA)</kbd>.